# Groupby and sum datetime64 dates by several days of a weekend in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have seen multiple questions where data is grouped by day of the week, but I did not find any questions where data is grouped by several days together.

I have a dataset

```
   date    day_type     bus  rail_boardings  total_rides
6636 2019-01-01        U  248879          245852       494731
6637 2019-01-02        W  591006          573542      1164548
6638 2019-01-03        W  664442          627781      1292223
6639 2019-01-04        W  668812          628514      1297326
6640 2019-01-05        A  444434          348257       792691
```

As you can see, I have day_type where W = Weekday, A = Saturday, U = Sunday/Holiday.

I would like to show the drop in the activity on aggregated weekends specifically (Friday/Saturday/Sunday) without holidays and visualize as a time series, using pandas and matplotlib. It will allow me to compare the activities on weekends between 2019 and 2020. Saturday date can be a date in a date column (or Friday, or Sunday, does not matter).

Ideal output:

```
date                day_type   bus      rail_boardings  total_rides
6636 2019-01-01        Weekend 1  248879          245852       494731
6637 2019-01-07        Weekend 2  591006          573542      1164548
6638 2019-01-14        Weekend 3  664442          627781      1292223
```

Appreciate any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking here a customized solution, esp. by the classification of Saturday and Sunday in different bins, like

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=50, freq='d'), 'value':[1]*50})
map_days = {
    6: 'A',
    5: 'U',
    4: 'W',
    3: 'W',
    2: 'W',
    1: 'W',
    0: 'W'}
df=df.assign(grouper=lambda x:x['date'].dt.weekday.map(map_days))
df.groupby('grouper')['value'].count()
```

Otherwise you could also work with pandas buildin business days, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-custombusinessdays but there you are always getting a binary classification.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time! The first solution is not exactly what I want, but thanks for the second tip! Will check.